# fanuc roboguide with ROS MoveIt (cont)

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, fanuc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

My question concerns about specific details needed so that we can see movements that occur inside `ROS/MoveIt/Rviz` also in the simulated robot inside `Roboguide`.

Briefly, I use `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS bionic` and  `ros-melodic`.  I have **ROS/Moveit** respositories for fanuc. I downloaded, installed and built these repositories from [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc_driver) under my `catkin_ws`.

On Windows side, I have installed `Roboguide`. I have followed  [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc/Tutorials/hydro/Installation) and  [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc/Tutorials/hydro/Configuration)  to make necessary configurations inside `Roboguide` on the virtual controller. When creating the work-cell, I chose `R-1000iA/80F` robot model.

On the TP, I have started the ROS TPE program. The following message appears:

```
25456     RSTA Waiting for ROS state prox
```

then I run the following on a terminal in ROS pc.

```
roslaunch fanuc_r1000ia80f_moveit_config moveit_planning_execution.launch robot_ip:=192.168.0.4 use_bswap:=false
```

Immediately, the following message appears on TP.

```
25460      RSTA Connected.
```

Within `rviz`, using the motion planning plugin, I can `plan` a very simple movement specifying an end state. Last time, I was able to see the movements carried out in `rviz` being done in `Roboguide`. However, recently, when I try to `execute`, it `fails` without a successful execution on the virtual controller.

I was getting the following errors on the terminal in my ROS PC.

```
[ERROR] [1234567890.123456789]: Controller is taking too long to execute trajectory (the expected upper bound for the trajectory execution was X.Y seconds). Stopping trajectory.
[ INFO] [1234567890.123456789]: MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Cancelling execution for
[ INFO] [1234567890.123456789]: Execution completed: TIMED_OUT
```

I followed the suggestion given [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/196586/how-do-i-disable-execution_duration_monitoring/). Specifically, I added the following lines to the `trajectory_execution.launch.xml` file.

```
<param name="trajectory_execution/allowed_execution_duration_scaling" value="4.0"/> <!-- default 1.2 -->
  <param name="trajectory_execution/execution_duration_monitoring" value="false" />
```

Now, `rviz` does not report a `failed` status when pressed `execute` or `plan & execute`. However, the movements do not appear on the virtual robot.

thanks,

Zahid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359684/fanuc-roboguide-with-ros-moveit-(cont)/) by [zahid990170](https://answers.ros.org/users/50178/zahid990170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 135 on 2020-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Disabling the trajectory execution monitor does not influence the execution of the motion (or: it does, but not in the way you describe, ie: not starting at all).

> On the TP, I have started the ROS TPE program

How exactly do you do this?

I ask because you only report messages on the TP from the robot state program. If only that program is running, you will not be able to command motion. For that, the trajectory relay must also be running.

Please open `http://192.168.0.4/MD/PRGSTATE.DG` and verify the following programs have a `running` status: `ROS_STATE`, `ROS_RELAY` and `ROS_MOVESM`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zahid990170](https://answers.ros.org/users/50178/zahid990170/) on 2020-08-17**:
thanks @gvdhoorn, answering your question.

I did `SELECT->TYPE->TP Programs->ROS` and then `SHIFT` followed by `FWD`. yes,  the trajectory relay must also be running. I was unable to figure out, on some occasions, I got the following on TP terminal output

```
RSTA waiting for ROS state prox
PREL waiting for ROS traj relay
```

and sometimes it was only

```
RSTA waiting for ROS state prox
```

When it was the two, I was able to command motion from `ROS` side. Otherwise not.

On the last try, I double click `ROS` such that it shows its contents

```
RUN ROS_STATE
RUN ROS_RELAY
CALL ROS_MOVESM
```

So, this runs the needed program.
then I go back and follow the aforementioned procedure to start the program ROS. This time, it runs both, and motion commands are passing  the virtual controller. thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-17**:
Could you please mark the question as answered by ticking the checkmark (✓) to the left of the answer if you feel it has been answered? Thanks.